# tabulator is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabulator

I am following quick start guide in tabulator(v4.2+) - http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/quickstart which worked as expected, when I included a button click function inside my html script I get .tabulator is not a function error and the table variable seems to be printing undefined in the browser console,

When i try to print in the browser console it returns table object but not console.log from the code

```css
var tabledata = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Oli Bob",
  age: "12",
  col: "red",
  dob: ""
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Mary May",
  age: "1",
  col: "blue",
  dob: "14/05/1982"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Christine Lobowski",
  age: "42",
  col: "green",
  dob: "22/05/1982"
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: "Brendon Philips",
  age: "125",
  col: "orange",
  dob: "01/08/1980"
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: "Margret Marmajuke",
  age: "16",
  col: "yellow",
  dob: "31/01/1999"
}, ];

table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  height: 200,
  data: tabledata,
  layout: "fitColumns",
  columns: [{
    title: "Name",
    field: "name",
    width: 150
  }, {
    title: "Age",
    field: "age",
    align: "left",
    formatter: "progress"
  }, {
    title: "Favourite Color",
    field: "col"
  }, {
    title: "Date Of Birth",
    field: "dob",
    sorter: "date",
    align: "center"
  }, ],
  rowClick: function(e, row) { 
    alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
  },
});
console.log(table);

$("#savebtn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(table)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment2"></label>
  <div id="example-table"></div>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Save" id="savebtn" />
```

The error is coming in this part of the code when the button click happens, table object is printing as undefined ?

```
$("#savebtn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(table)
});
```

Comment: There are two possibilities, you're executing your JS code before tabulator is loaded or it's not loaded at all and you have error in console that you get 404 or 500 error from server. Where you've put your JS code inside html? Do you have error in console?

Comment: Please add the missing code so the snippet showcases your problem.

Comment: @jcubic I am able to load the tabulator table without a problem, however when there is a button click I am getting undefined when I am trying to print  the table variable

Comment: I dont understand why console.log(table) is returning undefined inside the button click , while the table has loaded without any problems on page load

Answer (score 0):

> Use var keyword
>
> ```
> var table = new Tabulator(
> ```

```js
const tabledata = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Oli Bob",
  age: "12",
  col: "red",
  dob: ""
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Mary May",
  age: "1",
  col: "blue",
  dob: "14/05/1982"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Christine Lobowski",
  age: "42",
  col: "green",
  dob: "22/05/1982"
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: "Brendon Philips",
  age: "125",
  col: "orange",
  dob: "01/08/1980"
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: "Margret Marmajuke",
  age: "16",
  col: "yellow",
  dob: "31/01/1999"
}, ];

const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  height: 200,
  data: tabledata,
  layout: "fitColumns",
  columns: [{
    title: "Name",
    field: "name",
    width: 150
  }, {
    title: "Age",
    field: "age",
    align: "left",
    formatter: "progress"
  }, {
    title: "Favourite Color",
    field: "col"
  }, {
    title: "Date Of Birth",
    field: "dob",
    sorter: "date",
    align: "center"
  }, ],
  rowClick: function(e, row) {
    alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
  },
});
console.log(table.getData());

$("#savebtn").click(function(e) {
 // e.preventDefault()
 // console.log(table.getData());
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="comment2"></label>
    <div id="example-table"></div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Save" id="savebtn" />
</body>

</html>
```